# Can javascript code served by a server under HTTPS talk to another server under a subdomain with a different certificate?

Tags: tls, certificates

Lets assume we have two servers :

(1) https://adomain.com

(2) https://abc.x.adomain.com

The each have **different** certificates, (2) has a wildcard and (1) does not.

If we remove https from the picture, the two servers can "share" cookies provided that the cookies have domain=".adomain.com"

## questions :

1. Can a page served by (1) call (2) by javascript ?
2. Can (1) and (2) "share" cookies ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a page served by (1) call (2) by javascript ?

Yes, using Cross-origin resource sharing (aka CORS).

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://adomain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST
```

> Can (1) and (2) "share" cookies ?

Yes, you can share cookies setting them to domain = ".adomain.com".